# Code ignores a line where should be thrown an exception while debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have a block of code where I tried to fix an exception. If you start the program it is normally showing me that in that line is an exception (access violation writing location). But when I set a breakpoint at this place (I have to click approx. 20 times on continue, apperantly the function is called multiple times) there does not appear an exception. The program starts and I can see a window with some components in it but then breaks and an exception appears at another place. How would you explain this phenomenon?

This is the code if you are asking:

```
FARPROC old_evhndl = (FARPROC)(obj->old_eventhandler());
...
LRESULT lRes = CallWindowProc(old_evhndl, hwnd, msg, (WPARAM)wParam, (LPARAM)lParam);
```

The exception is pointing to CallWindowProc and when I comment the first line out there is also no exception at this place. old_evhndl is also used in the same function, above this implementation.

Comment: It's called *undefined behaviour*. Badly written programs have undefined behaviour and seeing different behaviours when running them under different circumstances is quite common. There's not enough code shown to say what your actual problem is.

Comment: As with your previous 2 questions we need a [mre], you have a race condition or other undefined behaviour somewhere its not unusual for these cases to behave differently in the debugger as the timing of the program completely changes